# Swift 3 my game over code doesn't work correctly

Tags: swift, function, sprite-kit, swift3, scene

If I touch besides of the buttons the game crash down. What can I do? And how? I want to ignore all touches which is besides of the buttons. How can I do that?
Here is my touchesBegan:

```
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    if let location = touch?.location(in: self),
        let node = self.nodes(at: location).first {

        var player = SKSpriteNode()

        if node.name == "BlueButton" {
            player = playerB
            playerB.isHidden = false

        } else if node.name == "RedButton" {
            player = playerR
            playerR.isHidden = false

        } else if node.name == "YellowButton" {
            player = playerY
            playerY.isHidden = false

        } else if node.name == "GreenButton" {
            player = playerG
            playerG.isHidden = false

        }
        for sprite in [playerB, playerW, playerR, playerY, playerG] {
            sprite?.removeFromParent()
        }
        player.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -60)
        addChild(player)
    }

}
```

Here is my touchesEnded function

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    addChild(playerW)
    playerB.removeFromParent()
    playerR.removeFromParent()
    playerY.removeFromParent()
    playerG.removeFromParent()

}
```

Comment: I do understand your English. I also note that your final *else* is *gameOver()*. Despite **not** debugging your code (apologies) my question is this: Is it always hitting this no matter what? More to the point of good questions, can you give me something I can verify and reproduce? Have you done any debuting with breakpoints?

Comment: So the first time if I push the right button it's work, but than every time print out the game over...

Comment: And I haven't any breakpoints. It' just not work correctly

Comment: So, then set a breakpoint and figure out why every time except the first is executing the else clause!

Comment: Okay I set a breakpoint to func didBegin, and I run the game, what is the next step? Sorry I'm really beginner :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the discussion in my other answer I *guess* that the complexity of your `touchesBegan` leads you to add more than one version of a player-sprite occasionally. The below should only add each playerSprite *once* and only *one at a time* which should make it easier to avoid unintended contacts due to sprites covering sprites etc...

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    if let location = touch?.location(in: self),
        let node = self.nodes(at: location).first {

        var player = SKSpriteNode()

        if node.name == "BlueButton" {
            player = playerB
        } else if node.name == "RedButton" {
            player = playerR
        } else if node.name == "YellowButton" {
            player = playerY
        } else if node.name == "GreenButton" {
            player = playerG
        }
        for sprite in [playerB, playerW, playerR, playerY, playerG] {
            sprite.removeFromParent()
        }
        player.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -50)
        addChild(player)
    }
}
```

Comment: :-) Glad to hear it.

Comment: Still not :/ the problem is the same just later... if I push the green button after the yellow button, or after the blue button push the green button and reverse :/

Comment: If I were you I would have a long look at those `addPlayer` functions as well as how/when you create the sprites. My guess is that they are not needed, and that you somewhere wind up calling them or add duplicate nodes with the same identifier elsewhere. Have you inspected the `children` property of your scene to see if this shows something fishy?

Comment: I would suggest a refactoring to have them return an instance, set each playerProperty equal to the appropriate instance and add it to the scene _only_ in `didMove(to view`

Comment: I can't understand it pretty well.. Sorry I'm really beginner

Comment: My guess is that you're still winding up with duplicate sprites somewhere. I would check if you call those `addPlayer` functions more than once or if you add the sprites with addChild somewhere else as well.

Comment: Hi! I found the problem.. But i don't know how can I solve it. The problem is by the touches ended function, if I remove all that code than run the game. But than the white player doesn't come back when touches ended so what can I do?

Comment: I'm not sure what the game-flow is supposed to be exactly, (what is supposed to happen when touchesEnd?). Are the sprites moving at any time? I still think you should considering to restructure how and _when_ you add these sprites. From the little I _do_ know about your game however it might be as simple as replacing your current `touchesEnded` with `addChild(playerW)`

Comment: Now it work!! Thank you for the lots of help! I have only a last question: When I push two button together or I touch on the screen besides the buttons the game crash down. What can I do?

Comment: I know this code if node.count > 0, but than I have an error message SKNode has no member 'count'

Comment: What does the crash say. Guessing (again) but perhaps it's because you're adding a node that already has a parent?

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: I want to ignore touches if it's besides of the buttons.

Comment: The `didBeginContact` above already does that, but you need to handle this appropriately in `touchesEnded` as well...

Comment: I dont understand how can i do that... I refresh my question top of the screen, that is the code what I use now.

Comment: You really need to stop and think about _exactly_ what you are trying to achieve. Your current touchesDidEnd somewhat suggests to me that you are more or less trying out things at random. (although, ironically, _chances_ are the bug might be fixes simply by reversing the order of the two statements).

Comment: I want to make that if you touch the buttons change the players and when touch is ended the white player come back. And when you touch the screen besides the buttons do nothing.

Comment: It's approaching a point where it is becoming hard for me to give any sensible advice. I don't know the architecture of your code, and the fact that you've included those `player.hidden` statements in your `touchesBegan` tells me that your implementation does not match the ideas I've tried to lay out for you. You can of course check if the whitePlayer has a parent which would probably solve the particular problem, but I will not be answering any further questions in this discussion, make a new one, or send me a PM if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

I think this condition

```
if firstBody.node?.name == "BLUE" && secondBody.node?.name == "BLUEBLOCK" ||
   firstBody.node?.name == "RED" && secondBody.node?.name == "REDBLOCK" ||
   firstBody.node?.name == "YELLOW" && secondBody.node?.name == "YELLOWBLOCK" &&
   firstBody.node?.name == "GREEN" && secondBody.node?.name == "GREENBLOCK"
```

should looks like

```
if (firstBody.node?.name == "BLUE" && secondBody.node?.name == "BLUEBLOCK") ||
   (firstBody.node?.name == "RED" && secondBody.node?.name == "REDBLOCK") ||
   (firstBody.node?.name == "YELLOW" && secondBody.node?.name == "YELLOWBLOCK") ||
   (firstBody.node?.name == "GREEN" && secondBody.node?.name == "GREENBLOCK")
```

It still looks ugly, but have to work

Comment: The problem is the same :/

Answer (score 1):

OK, frankly it's a bit of a mess, the didBeginContact function in particular. If I read you intent correctly it's supposed to go something like this:

- Any contact with the "white" block should end the game.
- For the other colors contacts with all but *one* particular color should end the game.
- Contact *with* the specific color should increase the score.

If this is indeed what we're aiming for something like the below should probably work, although I would still recommend further refactoring to avoid basing such a vital part of your game-logic on flakey string-matching:

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    guard let nodeA = contact.bodyA.node else { 
        // this and the one blow are good places to add a breakpoint to inspect what's going on if still having problems
        return 
    }  
    guard let nodeB = contact.bodyB.node else { 
         return 
    }

    // Some Bools to make the below logic more readable
    let blueContacted = nodeA.name == "BLUEBLOCK" || nodeB.name == "BLUEBLOCK"
    let redContacted = nodeA.name == "REDBLOCK" || nodeB.name == "REDBLOCK"
    let yellowContacted = nodeA.name == "YELLOWBLOCK" || nodeB.name == "YELLOWBLOCK"
    let greenContacted = nodeA.name == "GREENBLOCK" || nodeB.name == "GREENBLOCK"

    var removableNodeName: String?

    if blueContacted && yellowContacted {
        removableNodeName = "YELLOWBLOCK"
    } else if redContacted && greenContacted {
        removableNodeName = "GREENBLOCK"
    } else if yellowContacted && blueContacted {
        removableNodeName = "BLUEBLOCK"
    } else if greenContacted && redContacted {
        removableNodeName = "REDBLOCK"
    }

    if let nodeName = removableNodeName {
        score += 1
        scoreLabel?.text = "\(score)"
        if nodeA.name == nodeName {
            nodeA.run(SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0 , y: 360), duration: 0.3))
            nodeA.run(SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 0.3))
        } else {
            nodeB.run(SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0 , y: 360), duration: 0.3))
            nodeB.run(SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 0.3))
        }
    } else { // Any other contact means game over
        nodeA.removeFromParent()
        nodeB.removeFromParent()
        score = 0
        scoreLabel?.text = "\(score)"
        gameOver()
    }
}
```

Edit: Added some guards to check for the existence of node on physicsBodies based on the discussion below.

Comment: I get a fatal error message, when I use this code..(unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value)

Comment: Where exactly? Perhaps in the part creating the Bools? If so this would indicate that you either have some contacts registering that you don't care about OR that you have not set up the nodes with names...

Comment: let nodeA = contact.bodyA.node! or let nodeB = contact.bodyB.node! on the top

Comment: Ok. This means the physicsBodies does not have a node. I would suggest using a guard to make sure you don't trigger this code unless this is the case.

Comment: Okay it's work, but in my game are 4 block type (blueblock,redblock,greenblock,yellowblock) and 4 player type(blue,red,yellow,green) and you have 4 button (blue,red,yellow,green) and which you push, the player change that color. So we have contact between blocks and players. And when the first time I push the right button my score will be 2 (from 0 to 2), and than when come a different color block than no matter which button I push the score will be 0 and game is over..But than everything work perfectly only in the first 2 blocks are this problem.

Comment: From what I can see you _add_ a blue player _every single time_ you tap the blue button (the same goes for the other colors). Is this really what you want to achieve?

Comment: A (slightly) wild guess would be that the constant creation of bluePlayer, redPlayer etc. aren't properly cleaned up, and that you simply cover the existing player with a new one, meaning you'll have a game-ending contact happen even if you can't really see it...